# Threading in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How single threaded architecture makes node js more efficient than a multi threaded architecture?

> A Node.js app runs in a single process, without creating a new thread for every request. Node.js provides a set of asynchronous I/O primitives in its standard library that prevent JavaScript code from blocking and generally, libraries in Node.js are written using non-blocking paradigms, making blocking behavior the exception rather than the norm.

[reference for above sentence(node js documentation)](https://nodejs.dev/learn)

Comment: Where does it say that this is more efficient?

Comment: than why it uses a single threaded architecture

Comment: Because Javascript is single threaded.   The term single threaded is often miss-leading, node.js is not a single threaded architecture, it's just that it's main entry point uses an an event loop.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

Using a single thread eliminate some classes of bugs (race conditions). Using evented IO improves performance for some workloads (mostly IO-bound with many simultaneous connections)